# Change the width of difflib.make_file() HTML Table?

Tags: python, html, css, html-table, difflib

I am creating diff files for legal documents with the python difflib and make_file(), which outputs HTML files containing a Table with the Diffs.

But the output tables are so wide that they are unreadable.

Is there any way to change the width of the table or add other css from my function call? I can't find anything related in the documentation.

In case it is not possible, what could be a solution to my "table width too wide" problem?

I already tried adding bootstrap and putting the table into a div that is responsive, but it didn't work.

Comment: see source code [difflib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py) - it uses hidden variable `_styles` and `_template` which you could use to assign own styles and own HTML template. Besides there is `wrapcolumn` in class `HtmlDiff` which could help to make it shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wrapcolumn=` in `HtmlDiff`

```
import difflib
import webbrowser

d = difflib.HtmlDiff(wrapcolumn=10)

lines1 = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']
lines2 = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXaaaaaaaaaYYYaaaaaaZZZZZZZZZZZaaaaZZZZZZZZ']

html = d.make_file(lines1, lines2)

with open('output.html', 'w') as fh: 
    fh.write(html)

webbrowser.open('output.html')
```

Without `wrapcolumn=`

[image]

With `wrapcolumn=10`

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I didn't test it but in source code of [diff](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py) you can see hidden variables [_styles](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L1670), [_table_template](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L1679), [_file_template](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L1650) which you could replace in [HtmlDiff](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L1706) to generate different HTML. This way you could add classes and styles to format it.

It may also need to change hidden [_format_line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L1899) to remove `nowrap="nowrap"`

---

**EDIT:**

I use `HtmlDiff` to create own class with new `_format_line()` without `nowrap="nowrap"` and now I can add styles with `width` and `word-break`

```
import difflib
import webbrowser

# --- classes ---

class MyHTML(difflib.HtmlDiff):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   
        # append new styles inside new class 
        self._styles = self._styles + """
table.diff {width: 300px}
.diff_sub {display: inline-block; word-break: break-word;}
.diff_add {display: inline-block; word-break: break-word;}
"""

    # function from source code - I remove only `nowrap="nowrap"`
    def _format_line(self,side,flag,linenum,text):
        """Returns HTML markup of "from" / "to" text lines
        side -- 0 or 1 indicating "from" or "to" text
        flag -- indicates if difference on line
        linenum -- line number (used for line number column)
        text -- line text to be marked up
        """
        try:
            linenum = '%d' % linenum
            id = ' id="%s%s"' % (self._prefix[side],linenum)
        except TypeError:
            # handle blank lines where linenum is '>' or ''
            id = ''
        # replace those things that would get confused with HTML symbols
        text=text.replace("&","&amp;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("<","&lt;")

        # make space non-breakable so they don't get compressed or line wrapped
        text = text.replace(' ','&nbsp;').rstrip()

        return '<td class="diff_header"%s>%s</td><td>%s</td>' \
               % (id,linenum,text)

# --- main ---

d = MyHTML()

# >>> changing styles after creating `MyHTML` or in original `HtmlDiff <<<
#d._styles = d._styles + """
#table.diff {width: 300px}
#.diff_sub {display: inline-block; word-break: break-word;}
#.diff_add {display: inline-block; word-break: break-word;}
#"""

#d._file_template = """new template"""
    

lines1 = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']
lines2 = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXaaaaaaaaaYYYaaaaaaZZZZZZZZZZZaaaaZZZZZZZZ']

html = d.make_file(lines1, lines2)

with open('output.html', 'w') as fh: 
    fh.write(html)

webbrowser.open('output.html')
```

---

Shorter version

```
import difflib
import webbrowser

d = HtmlDiff(wrapcolumn=10)

d._file_template = """new template with %(charset)s %(styles)s %(table)s %(legend)s"""         
#d._styles = """new styles"""         

lines1 = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']
lines2 = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXaaaaaaaaaYYYaaaaaaZZZZZZZZZZZaaaaZZZZZZZZ']

html = d.make_file(lines1, lines2)

with open('output.html', 'w') as fh: 
    fh.write(html)

webbrowser.open('output.html')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Wrapcolumn did the trick for the width. Can you give me an example for a call e.g. with a modified _file_template? I set a variable file='''<!DOCTYPE.... ''' and used _file_template=file in the function call, but it doesn't work

Comment: I made example which change `_styles`. If you don't need to modify functions in `HtmlDiff`  then you can use `d = HtmlDiff(wrapcolumn=10)` and `d._file_template = """new template"""`